# git: error: failed to push some refs to repo

Tags: git

I'm using Git 1.7.5.1 on Win XP.  I want to tag the current version of the code I'm working on and push that tag to the remote repository.  I'm able to tag the local copy, but when I try and push I get some errors.  Here's what I get ...

```
username@DCHI075438 ~/workspace/iteration1
$ git tag qa_release

username@DCHI075438 ~/workspace/iteration1
$ git push origin qa_release
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: + refs/tags/qa_release username DENIED by refs/tags/
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/tags/qa_release
To ssh://myuser@my_repo/cit_pplus.git
 ! [remote rejected] qa_release -> qa_release (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://myuser@my_repo/cit_pplus.git'
```

Any ideas what's wrong?  How can I correct this?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

The output of `git push` says:

```
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/tags/qa_release
```

That means that the repository you are pushing to has a hook and that hook rejects your commits. It's possible that pushing tags is not allowed or that you do not have permissions to do so.

Note that the proper way to push tags to a remote repository is to use `git push --tags`.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are seeing is now git issue, but due to a pre-receive hook on the remote repository you are pushing to. It looks more like some bug in the hook, as indicated by this line from the hook:

```
remote: + refs/tags/qa_release username DENIED by refs/tags/
```

Talk to the administrator for the remote repo / server and see what's happening in the hook.